# javascript bookmarklet calling another function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a javascript function to modify a page its Dom elements.  Since I am doing the same thing 6 times i would like to call a function from the first function.  Not quite sure how I can do that.

```
javascript:(function(){
//DoStuff
}());
```

I have working javascript inside that block and this executes as it should

However now i want to do something like this:

```
javascript:(function(){
function AlterPage()
{
    ModifySector(0);
    ModifySector(1);
    ModifySector(2);
    ModifySector(3);
    ModifySector(4);
    ModifySector(5);
}

function ModifySector(sectorNumber)
{
    //DoStuff
}}());
```

So I am now trying to call the same code that executes above 6 times, with a different parameter.  This does not work at all.  It this at all possible without creating an external script file?  And if so... how?

Comment: Use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what's going on but it seems to only be you are invoking the `ModifySector();`
but not the `AlterPage();`
so nothing will happen.

something like this may work:

store it all in an array and use a helper...

```
const myArr = ['dog','cat','turtle','snake','hamster','fish']

function AlterPage(sectorNumber){
    ModifySector(sectorNumber);
}

function ModifySector(sectorNumber)
{
  console.log(sectorNumber);
    //DoStuff
}


myArr.forEach((e) => {
    AlterPage(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i am an idiot.  I only needed to actually call the function and it worked :)

```
javascript:(function(){
AlterPage();
function AlterPage()
{
    ModifySector(0);
    ModifySector(1);
    ModifySector(2);
    ModifySector(3);
    ModifySector(4);
    ModifySector(5);
}

function ModifySector(sectorNumber)
{
    //DoStuff
}}());
```

that does the trick